Quantum hall effect, quantum spin hall effect and Topological Insulator
In the Quantum Hall Effect, we have edge states, which are responsible for the conduction in the system; these edge states are called Chiral edge states, and they give rise to what is called the Topological Insulator.
In the Quantum Spin Hall Effect, we have edge states, which are basically due to the spin of the electron; these edge states are called Helical edge states.
My Questions are following

How exactly is this concept of edge states changing while going from the Quantum Hall Effect to the Quantum Spin Hall  effect?

How does this change affect the definition of a Topological insulator?

Why they are called Chiral edge states and Helical edge states, is there any reason behind this or is it just nomenclature?

Does it has anything to do with Topological Invariant?


If possible, provide some mathematical description of the answer also!
